# php GD draw a straight line in angle

Tags: php, image, gd

I made that picture in PHP GD, But its have a small problem with lines.

[image]

The lines you see is created by `imageline()`.

So when I create a line with an angle using it, the lines had some noises.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you considered using a library that supports antialiasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly try with [`imageantialias()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php). Something like

```
imageantialias($image, true);
```

which will result a line *a little bit* better looking than yours.

Comment: As I said *a little bit* better than the non-anitialiased one. Anyway, glad it (somewhat) helps.